# prevent LinodeStackScript closing sub-processes after it's finished

Tags: bash, linode

In my StackScript (for Linode):

```
apt-get -qy install xserver-xorg-core openbox --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests
apt-get -qy install xinit tint2
setsid startx &
...
```

When the script ends, it closes the X-screen.
How can I make the X-screen to remain?
(*setsid* doesn't help)

Comment: Where are you expecting the X server to be displayed?

Comment: In Glish. https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/using-the-linode-graphical-shell-glish/

Comment: It's for automation, so Puppeteer (browser) can run in a `headless=false` mode.